# How to check evaluation auc after every epoch when using tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I defined my model using tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec. I know it has train, evaluation and prediction modes. But I want to check some metric scores such as auc after every epoch. Does this API support it like keras?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API for adding Metrics like `AUC` but you can create `Custom Metric Function` using `tf.keras.metrics`, and then use those Metrics in Estimator, using `tf.estimator.add_metrics`.

Example code, which demonstrates the implementation of AUC is shown below:

```
  def my_auc(labels, predictions):
    auc_metric = tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name="my_auc")
    auc_metric.update_state(y_true=labels, y_pred=predictions['logistic'])
    return {'auc': auc_metric}

  estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(...)
  estimator = tf.estimator.add_metrics(estimator, my_auc)
  estimator.train(...)
  estimator.evaluate(...)
```

Or

```
  def my_auc(labels, predictions, features):
    auc_metric = tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name="my_auc")
    auc_metric.update_state(y_true=labels, y_pred=predictions['logistic'],
                            sample_weight=features['weight'])
    return {'auc': auc_metric}

  estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(...)
  estimator = tf.estimator.add_metrics(estimator, my_auc)
  estimator.train(...)
  estimator.evaluate(...)
```